# Why a minimum MFC project has linking error on Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, visual-studio-2013

I created a Win32 console application to write a simples MFC project.

[image]

The source code is as follow:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance();

    MyApp()
    {
    }
};

class MainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
protected:
    int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    void OnClose();
    LRESULT OnTimer(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    // This line is causing the error
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BOOL MyApp::InitInstance()
{
    MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    m_pMainWnd = mainWindow;
    mainWindow->Create(NULL, L"Main Window");
    mainWindow->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);

    return TRUE;
}

MyApp myApp;

int MainWindow::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    SetTimer(1, 2000, NULL);
    return 0;
}

void MainWindow::OnClose()
{
    if (MessageBox(L"Close?", L"Close", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
    {
        KillTimer(1);
        CFrameWnd::OnClose();
    }
}

LRESULT MainWindow::OnTimer(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONQUESTION);
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile I get the following error:

> Error 1   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual struct AFX_MSGMAP const * __thiscall MainWindow::GetMessageMap(void)const " (?GetMessageMap@MainWindow@@MBEPBUAFX_MSGMAP@@XZ) D:\Projects\MinimumMFC\MinimumMFC\MinimumMFC.obj    MinimumMFC

Comment: When creating a dialog application using MFC, did you have the option to:
1. Use MFC in a Shared DLL?

Comment: This does not look like a **Win32 console** application. Consider editing your question to match your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to declare the BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP after the MainWindow declaration:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MainWindow, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_TIMER, OnTimer)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

The full source code should be:

```
#include <afxwin.h>

class MyApp : public CWinApp
{
public:
    BOOL InitInstance();

    MyApp()
    {
    }
};

class MainWindow : public CFrameWnd
{
protected:
    afx_msg int OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct);
    afx_msg void OnClose();
    afx_msg LRESULT OnTimer(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MainWindow, CFrameWnd)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_CLOSE()
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_TIMER, OnTimer)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

BOOL MyApp::InitInstance()
{
    MainWindow* mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    m_pMainWnd = mainWindow;
    mainWindow->Create(NULL, L"Main Window");
    mainWindow->ShowWindow(m_nCmdShow);

    return TRUE;
}

MyApp myApp;

int MainWindow::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
{
    SetTimer(1, 2000, NULL);
    return 0;
}

void MainWindow::OnClose()
{
    if (MessageBox(L"Close?", L"Close", MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDYES)
    {
        KillTimer(1);
        CFrameWnd::OnClose();
    }
}

LRESULT MainWindow::OnTimer(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONQUESTION);
    return 0;
}
```